# How many possible ways are there to represent an integer $x$ by $n$ integers?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many possible ways can the number $x$ be build by the sum of the non-negative integers $x_i, \dots, x_n$, i.e. how many ways are there such that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x$.

So since $x_i$ are non-negative integers, there exists a finite number of possible combinations, but I am confused on what is the right formula to use. I am reformulating the problem as how many ways are there to distribute $x$ distinct balls to $n$ distinct boxes, which yields the formula $n^x$. But if I do a small example and set $x=10$ and $q=2$, my formula states there are $2^{10}=1024$ possible combination while in reality there are only $11$, namly: 0+10, 1+9, 2+8, 3+7, 4+6, 5+5, 6+4, 7+3, 8+2, 9+1, 10+0$.

Does anyone have the right answer?

Comment: The problem is identical to distributing $x$ identical object to n boxes. You might think of using $(n-1)$ identical separator to model the situation. Then just compute the permutations: $C(x+(n-1),n-1))$. In that case you're left with $C(10+2-1, 2-1)=11$

Comment: Hello, thank you. So my mistake was to assume they are distinct. What is C(x,y)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: The comment from @Salihcyilmaz is an application of *[Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))*